# Finding $c$ and $n_0$ in Big O proofs involving logarithms

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I need to write some Big O proofs involving logarithms and I don't know what I need to know regarding logarithms to solve these proofs. I've just never been good with logs. I need c and n0 values to justify my proofs. I don't exactly want an answer as much as I'd like to know how to approach any similar questions.

First, consider attempting to prove/disprove $f(n)$ is $O(5n^{1/4})$, where $f(n)$ is $5\log(n^5) + 10\log(\log(n^{10}))$.

The first thing I want to do is replace $\log\log n^{10}$ with the highest term in the function just like I'd replace $n^2$ with $n^3$ in a function like $n^3 + n^2$.
But what does the second term become? $5\log n^5 + 10\log n^5$, or something else?

After replacement of the second term, what can I do to get $c$? I'll have two log terms divided by $5n^{1/4} \leq c$, and I don't know what I can do in that situation.

Second, consider trying to prove/disprove $f(n)$ is $O(n^{5.2})$, where $f(n)$ is $10n^5 \log(n)$.

I tried doing:

$10n^5 \log(n) \leq cn^{5.2}$

$10 \log(n) /n^{0.2} \leq c$

But then I'm stuck as to getting a value for $c$ and $n_0$. My guess is that it has something to do with $n^{0.2} = n^{1/5}$.

I feel like I'm asking a lot but these questions are far above what examples exist in my textbook or what was shown in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, as always, the powers in the logarithms are throwing you off. We can simply the expression as follows:

$$\begin{align}5 \log (n^5)+10\log(\log(n^{10}))&=15\log n+10\log(10\log n)\\
&=15\log n+10\log(10)+10\log(\log n)\\&=15\log n+10+10\log(\log n)
\end{align}$$

Since $\log \log n$ grows slower than $\log n$, and the constant term doesn't grow at all, we can write for $n\ge 10$:

$$15\log n+10+10\log \log n<15\log n+10\log n+10\log n=35\log n$$

Now to find a large enough $n_0$ such that for $n\ge n_0$ we have $35\log n\le 5cn^{1/4}$ for some $c$.

To approach this kind of problem, remember that we are only talking about asymptotic behavior, so $n_0$ can be very large, say $n_0=10^4$. Here I chose $10$ because of the $\log$ and $4$ because of $n^{1/4}$.

We have $35\log n_0 = 140$ and $5n^{1/4} = 50$. Hence we choose $c=3$.

/*Finally to show that this really works, we choose any $n \ge n_0$. There is some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $10^{4k}\le n < 10^{4k+4}$. For this $k$, we observe:

$$5cn^{1/4}\ge15\cdot10^k>140(k+1)>35\log 10^{4k+4}$$

Unfortunately the middle inequality only holds true for $k\ge 2$, so I amend $n_0$ to $10^8$ for ease of argument.*/

Another way to show the result (starting from /* onwards) is to take the derivative of the difference

$$\frac d {dn}(5cn^{1/4}-35\log n)=\frac{15}{4n^{3/4}}-\frac{35}{n\ln 10}>\frac{3}{n^{3/4}}-\frac{3}{n} = \frac 3n(n^{1/4}-1)$$

and note that it is positive for $n>1$, showing that the difference is strictly increasing, and thus the inequality $35\log n\le 5cn^{1/4}$ holds for $n\ge 10^4$.

This should help you deal with the second question as well, which you have correctly reduced to showing the inequality $10\log n \le cn^{1/5}$ for large $n$.